# How to start single RTSP session with multiple video subsession(H264 & MPEG4) using live555?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, mpeg-4, live555

I am able to start single RTSP Server session with 2 H264 sub-session as both are supposed to have same SDP description but when my both sub-session are of a different type (1 H264 and 1 MPEG4 ) I am not able to start streaming.

Comment: Maybe you should post your SDP. In both case (2xH264 or 1xH264+1xMPEG4), you should have one line starting with `m=video` for each. live555 handle this.

Comment: @mpromonet Thanks it works. I am using live555, my actual problem was data for SDP as sometimes I don't have a video source(one or both) running.